Can anyone identify this WWII movie about a Japanese invasion?
Language: English
Setting: World War Two - Probably Singapore or Hong Kong
Produced: Unknown, could be 70ties and newer. Color movie or TV miniseries. I watched it around 1992 or 1993. 
Title: The word "China" could be part of the title, but it is also likely that it is not.
The movie or TV miniseries takes place during World War Two, in a city being invaded by the Japanese. 
I suspect it takes place in Hong Kong or Singapore during the Japanese invasion in WWII, but it could be elsewhere in Asia.
Plot
I believes it follows either a family, or a female character that has a friend or husband (possibly named Tim) in the British military. I think he is shot or wounded in one scene, laying next to a jeep, where she screams his name.
In one scene Japanese soldiers invade a hospital, where the wounded patients are laying in their beds.
A doctor points to his Red Cross arm band, to which a solider just shakes his head. He runs away, and is shot in the back by the Japanese. I believe they also kill nurses.
The Japanese proceed to bayoneting the patients. I remember one camera view from underneath a bed, where the bayonet runs straight through the patient, and through the bed. I think someone was hiding under the bed, but manages to escape by distracting the Japanese soldier by throwing something on the floor.
Can anyone help identify this movie?

The bayoneting of patients sounds like you're describing documented events in the battle of Hong Kong. The movie you saw may have borrowed events from that.
Battle of Hong Kong Wikipedia Entry - see St Stevens College
more info at legion magazine
I'm pretty sure it's not this but you can try it out, it was released around the time you think you saw it..
Savage Christmas - Hong Kong 1941

Hi Hastig,
Thank you! As you suspect, it is not the one, but for a brief second I thought that it could be. I think you are spot on that the movie has borrowed events from these actual incidents, even a soldier explaining how he escaped this type of massacre (as in the movie).
Thank you for your reply, much appreciated.
Best regards

The BBC may have done this in their WWII People's War series.
The events you describe occurred on Feb 12 1942 in Alexandra Hospital in Singapore after the Japanese invaded Singapore in Feb 1942 with the British and Allied troops surrendering to the Japanese. Japanese soldiers entered the hospital killing about 50 soldiers/staff then proceeded to kill doctors, nurses, patients and even those on operating tables by bayonets mostly, despite the soldier envoy surrendering with a white flag. Some of the soldiers who did this were executed by their Japanese commander and the event became part of the War Crimes hearings with executions meted out as punishment. Here is one account of that massacre: Alexander Military Hospital Unfortunately I do not know of a specific movie or TV show that depicted the BBC may have done this in their WWII People's War series.

If it is possibly from the 1990s, this might be Don't Cry, Nanking which is a 1995 movie about the Nanking Massacre (aka the Rape of Nanking).
There was also a movie about Nanking called Flowers of War (2011). I think I saw both, and they depict similar scenes if I recall.
As Wikipedia tells us:

The Nanking Massacre was an episode of mass murder and mass rape
  committed by Japanese troops against the residents of Nanjing (then
  spelled Nanking), then the capital of the Republic of China during the
  Second Sino-Japanese War.

Trailer for Don't Cry, Nanking (warning: has some depictions of violence or its aftermath):



